# Jquery dialog button - positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have three buttons in the page. one button need to top right and another two button should be bottom left.

So how to split the button positions in jQuery?

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    text-align: center;
}
```

How to include custom image?

Comment: Html code needed for better clarity. can you provide html code ?

Comment: include custom image where exactly?

Comment: These are jquery buttons ..so no html code..and custom images means insteadof buttons , just using newly created image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: none;
    position:absolute;

}
.ui-dialog  {
    top: 10px !important;
    right:5px;

}
.ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    top: 400px;(this value depends on the page layout)
    left: 10px;
}
```

if you wanna use jquery

```
$(.ui-dialog).css('top', '10px');
$(.ui-dialog).css('right', '5px');

$(.ui-dialog-buttonpane).css('top', '400px');
$(.ui-dialog-buttonpane).css('left', '5px');

$(.ui-dialog-buttonset).css('top', '400px');
$(.ui-dialog-buttonset).css('right', '10px');
```

wrap this code in document.ready function  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z8ZQF/4/

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset button:first-child {
   right:30px; 
   position: absolute;
   top: 42px;
}
.ui-dialog-buttonset{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I have implemented css code , all the buttons are came to bottom. i need one button at top right and other two are bottom left.I would like to know how to split the buttons pane.

Comment: Check the answer...I have made an edit using important in css code for top property

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8ZQF/1/ - Please check here...Search button should be right of text box and other buttons are left of bottom.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/z8ZQF/2/  ...Added appropriate css and updated fiddle

Comment: I looking for search button next to text box(right side of the text box in jsfiddle).

Comment: Search button Looks great...Edit and cancel buttons needs leftmost. is it possible can use .png or jpg images instead of these default buttons ?

Comment: Yes...you can use .png/jpg. Do the same css like I did for first-child. you can use second -child and third-child and then add background images. And make them leftmost too :)

Comment: Though quite old, thought of updating my observation - you can add CSS class to any button while defining it and drive it's style - seems more cleaner to me :-)